# Can't bind the § key on the Apple keyboard

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, apple

When creating a keyboard shortcut I can't use the <kbd>§</kbd> key on my Apple keyboard, which is located under the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. In elementary OS when the § key is pressed a < is returned. When I create a keyboard shortcut `Alt+§` (which results into `Alt+<`) it does create the shortcut but I can't use it by pressing `Alt+§`. I can then only use it by pressing `Alt+Shift+,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are comfortable trying to use the command line, but this is a known issue on Linux with some Apple keyboards.

[This Arch Wiki Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apple_Keyboard#.3C_and_.3E_have_changed_place_with_.C2.A7_and_.C2.BD) has instructions for fixing your exact situation. Please try this, and let me know if you are successful.